# Can I mark part of page as "duplicated content"

Tags: html, seo, duplicates

I have an online shop. Manufacturers of my products allow me to copy their descriptions.
To have some valuable content I am also adding (optionally) my own description and user comments. But on some product pages most of the text could be the copy-pasted description.

Can I explicitly mark part of my document as a duplicate content?

Pseudo code:

```
<h1>Product Description</h1>
blah blah blah...
<h1>Manufacturer Description</h1>
<duplicate of http://manufacturer.url>
    blah blah blah...
</duplicate>
<h1>User comments</h1>
blah blah blah...
```

Optionally can I make search engine bots ignore parts of document? without any tricks like replacing it with image etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use rel='canonical' to say Boot that the page has an original source. You can read more about this in [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394).

For hiding purposes, you can load the content in iFrames.

Alternatively, you can place the copied description on the very bottom of the page and place it to the right place using CSS. In this way, the content cannot survive from bots, but value will be too low. But this is not recommended as it is a black hat trick. But still just an answer to your question.

Comment: thank you. I am aware of rel='canonical' however it is specified in head for whole document. whole point of my question is to mark only part of page as duplicate. loading this part in iframe would probably do the trick but seems very nasty.